# how to insert/delete values from table using colum it does not have

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

hi i have 3 tables wDetails wstatusdeletelog and wStatus one have columns like StateId, DepotId Wid Bags and other(wstatus) have wid, PrintStatus,DateCreated now i want to insert all data of wstatus related to particular DepotId of wdetails into   wstatusdeletelog  table and after insertion delete same from wstatus.Please help
my table structure
 wDetails

```
State id     DepotId   Wid  Bags
    55         12345   145    10
    55         12345   146    20
    55         12345   147    20
    55         12389   189    30
```

Second table wstatus

```
   wid  PrintStatus   DateCreated
   145     y          2015/10/10
   146     y          2015/10/09
   147     N          2015/09/09
```

third table(wstatusdeletelog)

```
   wid   PrintStatus  Datedeleted
```

now i want to insert data of table wstatus to wstatusdeletelog where Depotid=12345
after that delete it from wstatus

Comment: can u explain more clear

Comment: consider using triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert values from wstatus but only where DepotID = 12345 you can do it by using insert from select where you join those two tables ( the one with data you want to insert and second one where you have the value of DepotID) :

```
    insert into wstatusdeletelog (wid,PrintStatus,Datedeleted)
    (select a.wid,a.PrintStatus,a.Datedeleted 
    from wstatus a join wDetails b on a.wid = b.wid 
    where b.depotID = 12345   )
```

Comment: but what about delete